# How to query axon aggregates

Tags: aggregate, axon

Is there a way to see the current state of the aggregates stored in axon?

Our application uses a Oracle backed axon event store.
I tried querying the domainevententry and snapshotevententry tables, but they are empty.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to see the current state of the aggregates stored in axon?

In short, yes, although it is **not recommended**. Granted, if you are planning to employ CQRS. CQRS, or Command-Query Responsibility Separation, dictates that the Command Model and the Query Model are separate.

The aggregate support Axon delivers supplies an easy means to construct a Command Model. As the name suggests, it's intended for commands. On the flip side, you have Query Models, which are designed for queries. AxonIQ has [this](https://axoniq.io/resources/cqrs) to say on CQRS; maybe that clarifies some things.

> I tried querying the domainevententry and snapshotevententry tables, but they are empty.

That's interesting on its own account! When you publish events in Axon, either through the `AggregateLifecycle#apply(Object...)` or `EventGateway#publish(Object...)` method, the published event should end up in your `domain_event_entry` table. If that's not the case, then either your JPA/JDBC configuration has a misser or some other exceptions occurring in your application.

Would you be able to update your issue with samples of your configuration and/or stack traces that you are seeing?

### Replaying production issues locally

What I've done in the past to be able to replay behavior occurring in a production environment is by loading the Aggregate's event stream from that environment into a local dev/test event store. To be able to query this, you only need the aggregate identifier. As the aggregate identifier is indexed, retrieving all events for a specific aggregate (differently named, the aggregate stream) is straightforward.

By doing so, I could run the application locally to flow through the aggregate step-by-step. This gave the benefit of knowing exactly which event caused what state change, leading to the problematic scenario.

However, *why* your events are not present in your `domainevententry` is unclear to me. If you're still facing issues with that, I still recommend that you update the question with more specifics on your project.

Comment: Wrt the first question, my goal is not to query the command model in code to use at runtime. The question is more if I can see the current state of my aggregate in some way, without having to put a breakpoint in my code and having to send a command so it is triggered.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for pointing that out, Marc. What would be the exact use case you'd need this for, though? 
One option I can think of is for you to invoke the `Repository<A>#load(String)` (where `A` is your aggregate class) to load the aggregate manually. This would net you the `Aggregate<A>` object, which in turn contains your aggregate.

Comment: My use case is to be able to see the current state of an aggregate to investigate if some business logic embedded in a command handler works as expected. I have a case where, depending on some state, we choose to ignore a command instead of emitting an event. I'd like to be able to check the state to see if this is why apparently a command is not processed, since there is no way to see the commands in axon (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: Alright, gotcha, thanks for that, @Marc. Wouldn't the test fixtures provided by the framework be sufficient here, though? If you validate all your command handlers with Axon's `AggregateTestFixture`, you shouldn't be required to check the internals as the internals define the outcome of your events. Furthermore, with event sourcing, the sole thing to validate are the events as they drive the state of your aggregate (in which ever future format you like) anyhow.

So, would that work for your scenario, Marc?

Comment: Steven.vanbeelen@axoniq.io that's all very nice, except in real life things do happen that you did not foresee during testing and when investigating an incident in a production environment it would be very convenient to be able to query an aggregate internal state.

Comment: And if those things you didn't foresee occur, you should still be able to validate that purely through commands and events, @Marc. Regardless, I can imagine you're not completely accustomed to this, as it's a different paradigm then most applications follow. 

Furthermore, there's still a way to achieve what you need to validate the scenario that occurred in production. You, however, cannot query the aggregate state directly in its _sourced_ format since you're dealing with an event stream format. I've updated my response to accompany some guidance in that area.